# How to have access using pointers on two type definition vectors

Tags: c++, vector, typedef

I'm trying to learn how I can use the different typedef vector, and after creating them how I can access the variables. I have commented as I wrote the code

```
  #include <iostream> 
    #include <vector>
    //#include <stdlib.h>
    
    using namespace std; 
    
    
    //Here I wanted to created a structure where I have position vector  
    struct Point { 
        double  pos;
    }; 
      
    // now I have the type  vector definitons  named List
    typedef std::vector<Point> List;
    
    
    int main() 
    { 
    
    //I have initialized two list which are List A, and List B 
    List A;
    List B;
    
    //Point a, and Point b are two double data type variables that I want to push back into the two kind of list
    Point a;
    Point b;
    for(int i =0; i<100; i ++){
    a.pos = 2*i+1;
    b.pos = 2*i -1;
    
      A.push_back(a);
      B.push_back(b);
    }  
        return 0; 
    }
```

Now my question is how I can access the variables from the two List that I have created. I want to have access to the same index vector.

This is how I tried with dereferencing the pointer, but I think I'm making some mistakes:

```
 for (List::iterator it = A->begin(); it != A->end(); it++) {
     Point* val = &(*it);
     cout <<  val->pos()<<endl; 
     
     //I need to access the  value from B list too
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that would work (assuming A and B are the same length):

```cpp
size_t jj = 0;
for (List::iterator it = A.begin(); it != A.end(); it++) {
    cout <<  it->pos<<endl; 
    cout << (B.begin() + jj)->pos<< endl;
    jj++;
}
```

Note that `A` and `B` are not pointers so you access their methods normally. By the way, if you have access to C++11 and above, you can use the following:

```
size_t ii = 0;
for (const auto& el: A) {
   cout << el.pos << "," << B.at(ii).pos << endl;
   ii++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you tell me about a bit about this portion of the code `(B.begin() + jj)`.

Comment: To get an iterator to the `n-th` element of an array using iterators, you basically get an iterator that points to the first element (i.e  `B.begin()` ) and then advance it to the `n-th` element, therefore `B.begin() + n`. Underneath, this is similar to pointer arithmetic in C, however C++ iterators ensure that the pointer arithmetic takes into account how big the object is (i.e it does `address_of_first_element + n * sizeof(element)` for you).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have printed out the index position: 
    `cout << "index A = "<<std::distance(A.begin(), it) << endl;
    cout << "index B =  "<<std::distance(B.begin() + jj, it) << endl;`

I thought the index of the two vectors would be the same  but it shows:
  index A =  0
index B =  -131


.

Should it not the result like this: 

index A =  0
index B =  0?

Comment: Note that the iterator `it` is only valid for `A` in the above example and getting the distance between `B.begin()` and `it` is not meaningful.  `auto it2=B.begin(); std::distance(B.begin() + jj, it2)` should print the value for `jj`.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with vectors, typedefs or anything else.

**`val->pos` is a `double`, not a function.**

So, remove the `()`:

```
Point* val = &(*it);
cout << val->pos << endl;
```

Or, a little more neatly:

```
const Point& val = *it;
std::cout << val.pos << '\n';
```